# Logged in user from session

Tags: php, session

Hey a question on session. I am trying to reflect a logged on user's username in the form in one of my webpage. However the data is reflecting another person username from the database. How do I make it reflect the person logging on as the username on the form? I already have the necessary data in the database. I just want it to reflect on the form the existing user who logged in.

```
    <?php session_start();  ?>
    <?
        $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `name` FROM `student_details` WHERE `name` =  '" . $adminName . "';");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>

    <td height="170">
      <table>
        <form method= "post" action="">
          <tr>
            <td>Student Name</td>
            <td><input name="Admin_no" type= "text" disabled="disabled" value= "<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"
       size="40" readonly> 
            </td>
          </tr>
```

This is how my login page looks like

```
?php session_start(); ?>
<?php 
  include("database.php");

    $adminName = $_POST['txtName'];
    $adminPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];

  $conn = dbConnect();

    if (!$conn)
        die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");

    $query = "select * from ohrm_user where user_name='$adminName' and user_password= '$adminPassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $query2 = "select * from ohrm_user where user_name='$adminName' and user_password= '$adminPassword'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2, $conn);
  $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

                $query3 = "select * from ohrm_user where user_name='$adminName' and user_password= '$adminPassword'";
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3, $conn);
  $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 && $row['user_role_id'] == 1)
    { 

  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $adminName;
  $_SESSION['user_password'] = $adminPassword;

    header('Location: adannouncement.php');
    }

  elseif   (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0 && $row2['user_role_id'] == 2)
{
    header('Location: home.php');
}
  elseif   (mysql_num_rows($result3) > 0 && $row3['user_role_id'] == 3)
{
    header('Location: SIPm_template.php');
}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Wrong Username or Password');
window.location='login.php';
</script>";
    } 

    dbDisconnect($conn);

?>
```

Comment: I think you should learn PHP, then you would know which variable contains your username. WWe have not enough code to know by ourselves, but it is probably in a case of the array $SESSION. But do you know what is a variable and what is an array ?

Comment: WHERE `name` =  '" . $adminName . "';" it s English, you just have to replace $adminName by the name of the currently logged user, but we cannot know where you stored it for you.

Comment: @Guilro yes I know. the variable $adminName is from the $SESSION from login page.

Comment: @Angelica  We need more information. Put `print_r($_SESSION);` after `session_start()` and tell us what it says (or at least which variable stores the `$adminName`.

Comment: it says ; Array ( ) @josh

Comment: @Angelica That doesn't sound right. `$_SESSION` is an array and `print_r()` will print an array in human-readable format. Are you giving me the info for `$adminName`?

Comment: @josh see my latest edit.